# Flutter Debugging in visual studio code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, debugging

When we use visual studio code for flutter programming, can we restrict debugging process to user files only? and forbid the debugger from opening and debugging external libraries during the debug session?

I used the debug setting at the bottom of the visual studio main window and set it to my code only, yet, the debugger keeps branching into external files when it reaches a return statement in the widget build method.

Sample statement that causes branching into external libraries during debugging
[image: sample statement that causes branching into external libraries during debugging]

Sample external library that joins into the debugging process
[image: Sample external library that goes into the debugging process]

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you can click a button on the bottom bar to toggle between `Debug my code` and `Debug my code + packages`'.

This button is only visible when you are in debug mode.

[image: here is example image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.
i tried this setting, yet it keeps jumping into external files, it does this behavior when it reaches a return statement in the widget build method.

I modified my question to reflect this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the behavior I described in my question was related to deep Uncaught exceptions.
Enabling All Exceptions and Uncaught Exceptions in the debug window assisted in further exploring the issue.
My issue was related to popping an out-of-context widget which caused abnormal behavior while debugging.